# How to use i5 2500K GPU on a Asrock P67 Fatal1ty boad

Tags: gpu

I have an Asrock P67 Fatal1ty board, and I'd like to use the GPU integrated in the i5 2500K CPU, but I have no idea how. I've got rid of my previous GPU (geforce 570) and now I'm stuck with no way to connect my rig to the monitor, be that VGA/DVI/HDMI, as I don't have any such exit on my motherboard. For the moment I don't want to buy another dedicated GPU. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you get rid of a dGPU that was better then your iGPU?  Your motherboard does not provide you the ability to use your iGPU.

Comment: I mean to change it so I've just sold the 570 but haven't yet bought the 970 I'm gunning for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from CPU support, you (also) need a motherboard that supports integrated graphics, and that board does not.

[image]

It was/is common for "gaming" motherboards to not support integrated video adapters, as they expect "gamers" to always want dedicated graphics adapters.

So you're options are to either go get another dedicated graphics adapter and install it, or replace the motherboard with one that supports integrated graphics.